# Feedback on Obout Controls especially the grid

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, obout

I could see this question asked but that was long time back but I want to know the latest feedback on Obout controls.
I am about to start the development of enterprise level application and is in process of selecting the grid, we have budget constraint but I am looking for the following features in the grid which I could see in oBout.

1. Excel like tabbing across cells.
2. Uploading the images at the row level.
3. Drag and drop rows
4. Autocomplete(suggestive) feature in the cell.
5. Master and child grid
6. Fixed header and columns.

Has anyone got experience of working on these features in OBOUT controls,how stable are those features? What about their support these days if I choose to goahead with Obout controls?
Also can I integrate bootstrap css in obout grid?

Comment: Obout has filed for bankruptcy. You can still download the controls but do not expect any support.

Comment: @NoBullMan, can you pass on any website address where this news can be confirmed?

Comment: I sent them a support request about a bug in their Editor in September and kept following up for an answer and never received one. I contacted their sales and told them about the situation and was told "unofficially" that a response won't be forthcoming because they have applied for a chapter 11 bankruptcy. Try sending them a support request and see what happens.

Comment: i've had a similar experience with no reply to a support email. can you link to a doc about the bankruptcy?